# Keras custom loss coupling different samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sample, loss

I am trying to understand how Keras actually computes the gradients of a custom loss in a general setting.
Normally losses are defined as a sum over the samples of independent contributions. This allows eventually a proper parallelisation in the computation of the gradients.
However, if I add a global non linearity on top of it, thus coupling the contribution of the individual samples, is Keras able to treat the differentiation properly?

In practice, is it actually minimising f(sum_i(x_i)) or computes it one sample at the time and thus reducing to sum_i(f(x_i))?

Below an example in the case of a log function.

`def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred): 
     return K.log(1+K.mean((y_pred-y_true)*(y_pred-y_true)))`

I have checked for documentation but I couldn't find any precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

It minimizes whatever you tell it to minimize.

- If you want to minimize the log of the whole sum, then apply the log after the sum.
- If you want to minimize the log of each sample and sum later, then apply the log before the sum

```py
def log_of_sum(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.log(1 + K.mean(K.square(y_true-y_pred)))

def sum_of_logs(y_true, y_ored):
    return K.mean(K.log(1 + K.square(y_true-y_pred))) 
    #mean is optional here - you can return all the samples and Keras will handle it
    #returning all the samples allows other functions to work, like sample_weights
```